# Query string to path in htaccess somewhat working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Hello I have been stuck with htaccess for the past 3 days and can not seem to figure out why my htaccess file is not changing my url correctly.

So I am attempting to turn this query string url from `www.example.com/test/user-profile.php?id=4` into `www.example.com/test/user-profile/4`

the /test/ in the url is not a file, its a folder in the main public_html directory.

Here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/user-profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/user-profile/%1? [R=301,L]
```

As of right now it is going to the url `www.example.com/test/user-profile/4` but it is not loading the entire page. Just beyond stuck, thank you for your time

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? "it is not loading the entire page" - what do you mean exactly by that?

Comment: my .htaccess file is in the main public_html folder. And it loads the page but the majority of css does not work, and my application.js file is console logging `'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' application.js:1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
##RewriteBase /test/
##Extrenal redirect rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(test/user-profile)\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  %1/%2?  [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$  $1/$2.php?id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late to the party and I've missed the previous comments (now deleted), but the above rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$  $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]`) doesn't rewrite the URL as stated in the question. It would rewrite `/test/user-profile/4` to `test.php?id=user-profile/4`, not `test/user-profile.php?id=4` as would seem to be required?

Comment: @MrWhite, condition picks up url `test/user-profile.php?id=4` that only as per last solution here. kindly do elaborate more so that I could edit the solution if required, cheers.

Comment: Yes, the first rule (redirect) is OK-ish. That would redirect `/test/user-profile.php?id=4` to `test/user-profile/4` (but `RewriteBase /` must also be set, otherwise the redirect will be malformed, since there is no slash prefix on the _substitution_ string). HOWEVER, the 2nd rule (the _rewrite_) does not reverse that, and would rewrite to `test.php?id=user-profile/4` instead, as mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: @MrWhite, oh thanks for letting know. There were lot of changes in code since OP was getting errors. Please do let me if this looks ok to you? cheers